# Bluetooth not working after upgrading from 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, bluetooth, 15.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04. After all the restarts, things were fine. I shut
the machine down.

Next morning, I restarted and my bluetooth keyboard (Logitech diNovo, about 6
years old) wasn't working. There was no bluetooth icon in the menu bar, and the
bluetooth tab in System Settings is entirely greyed out, with bluetooth off and
not able to be turned on.

I've successfully used this same keyboard with multiple
versions of Ubuntu back to 2009.

I googled around and found various people with similar problems. It might be
related to bluez being upgraded from version 4 to version 5? Not sure.

The Bluetooth device is detected:

```
[fjord:~] lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1058:0704 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. My Passport Essential (WDME)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 046d:c70c Logitech, Inc. BT Mini-Receiver (HID proxy mode)
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 046d:c70b Logitech, Inc. BT Mini-Receiver (HID proxy mode)
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 046d:0b02 Logitech, Inc. C-UV35 [Bluetooth Mini-Receiver] (HID proxy mode)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The single receiver widget is responsible for devices 019, 018 and 017 in that list. (If I unplug the widget, all three of those device lines disappear.)

But something is wrong:

```
[fjord:~] sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

and then:

```
[fjord:~] sudo service bluetooth start
[fjord:~] sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2015-05-21 16:09:46 PDT; 13min ago
 Main PID: 3709 (bluetoothd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─3709 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n

May 21 16:09:46 fjord bluetoothd[3709]: bluetoothd[3709]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
May 21 16:09:46 fjord bluetoothd[3709]: bluetoothd[3709]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
May 21 16:09:46 fjord bluetoothd[3709]: bluetoothd[3709]: Failed to init proximity plugin
May 21 16:09:46 fjord bluetoothd[3709]: bluetoothd[3709]: Failed to init time plugin
May 21 16:09:46 fjord bluetoothd[3709]: bluetoothd[3709]: Failed to init alert plugin
May 21 16:09:46 fjord bluetoothd[3709]: bluetoothd[3709]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
May 21 16:09:46 fjord bluetoothd[3709]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
May 21 16:09:46 fjord bluetoothd[3709]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
May 21 16:09:46 fjord bluetoothd[3709]: bluetoothd[3709]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
May 21 16:09:46 fjord bluetoothd[3709]: bluetoothd[3709]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
```

Other diagnostics:

```
[fjord:~] lsmod | grep bluetooth
bluetooth             491520  8 bnep,btusb

[fjord:~] uname -a
Linux fjord 3.19.0-18-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 19 18:31:35 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[fjord:~] dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.201123] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored

[fjord:~] bluetoothd -v
4.101
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Thank you.

**[update]** If I remove the USB dongle and reinsert it while holding the red button, I can get things to look like this:

```
[fjord:~] sudo service bluetooth status
    ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2015-05-24 03:11:26 PDT; 3min 50s ago
 Main PID: 2162 (bluetoothd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─2162 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd -n

May 24 03:12:47 fjord bluetoothd[2162]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoint/BlueZ4/HFPAG
May 24 03:12:47 fjord bluetoothd[2162]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoint/BlueZ4/HFPHS
May 24 03:12:47 fjord bluetoothd[2162]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoint/BlueZ4/A2DPSource
May 24 03:12:47 fjord bluetoothd[2162]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoint/BlueZ4/A2DPSink
May 24 03:12:47 fjord bluetoothd[2162]: bluetoothd[2162]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoint/BlueZ4/HFPAG
May 24 03:12:47 fjord bluetoothd[2162]: bluetoothd[2162]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoint/BlueZ4/HFPHS
May 24 03:12:47 fjord bluetoothd[2162]: bluetoothd[2162]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoint/BlueZ4/A2DPSource
May 24 03:12:47 fjord bluetoothd[2162]: bluetoothd[2162]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.44 path=/MediaEndpoint/BlueZ4/A2DPSink
May 24 03:12:47 fjord bluetoothd[2162]: Adapter /org/bluez/2162/hci0 has been enabled
May 24 03:12:47 fjord bluetoothd[2162]: bluetoothd[2162]: Adapter /org/bluez/2162/hci0 has been enabled
```

That looks healthier, but the keyboard is still not working.

Comment: Is there a red button on the USB dongle?  Try pressing the button for 3-5 seconds and hold the button when inserting it into the computer to see if bluetooth will work

Comment: Not quite, but it did change things a bit. I've updated the original question with the new information. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you copy the contents of /lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules and paste at paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL

Comment: Contents of/lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/11348000/

Comment: `sudo gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-hid2hci.rules`  And on line 14 change `"hiddev*"` to `"hidraw*"`  Save, exit, and reboot

Comment: This advice is similar to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/870227/comments/9, which suggested commenting out that line (and the following line). I now remember that worked for me 3.5 years ago when I had the same problem upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Having said that, the ultimate problem was actually... flat batteries :/  I changed them and now the keyboard is working again *without* any changes to the rules file. I figure the batteries must have run out just after I upgraded, and since upgrades have caused problems with this keyboard in the past I assumed incorrectly that it was an upgrade issue. Sorry for any confusion, and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was just flat batteries! The batteries must have died just after the upgrade so I incorrectly blamed the upgrade. Unlucky timing. Sorry for the noise.